# Apparent singularities and non Fuchsian regular points

Tags: singularity-theory, transcendental-number-theory

I am considering the following function of $z$ on the Riemann sphere:
$$
J(z) = \int_\Delta (L_0+z L_1)^a D^b d^nx
$$
where

- $\Delta \in H_n\big(\Bbb{CP}^n\setminus\{L(x)=0\},S\big)$, $S$ being the standard simplex,
- $L(x) = L_0(x)+zL_1(x)$, and $L_i(x),D(x)$ are polynomials of $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$ with integer coefficients.

**Lemma 1**: the singularities of $J(z)$ are contained in the set where $L$ or its restrictions $L|_I$ to coordinate planes define singular projective hypersurfaces ( assuming that for the generic $z$ it is a non singular hypersurface). Denote these points $z_{I,a}$

It is known that $J(z)$ defines a flat vector bundle with regular singularities (see Arnol'd-Varchenko-Gusein-Zade). One may be tempted to conjecture that $J(z)$ can be included into a bundle as follows
$$
\frac{dI(z)}{dz} = \sum \frac{A_{I,a}}{z-z_{I,a}} I 
$$
where $A_{I,a}$ are constant matrices, $J$ being one of the components of the vector function $I$.

Unfortunately, this does not follow from general principles because:

1. There can be non Fuchsian regular singularities, where the bundle equation has a pole of higher order, but the solution is still regular ( see Anosov Bolibrukh "The Riemann Hilbert problem" ch. 2)
2. There can be apparent singularities, where the equation is singular but the solution is not.

There is a large literature on each of these cases. In particular,
*Case 1*, in particular is treated in the works of Moser-Barkatou-Pfluger-... where the necessary conditions for regularity are studied.
*Case 2*, has very interesting connections to isomonodromic deformations, treated e.g. in the works of Vyugin, Gontsov ( see also Poberezhny, Eremenko, Cohen, Wolfart,....)

**Question**: do these complications arise in the case of the functions defined by the integral above?

There is evidence that they do not. The evidence comes from the existence of a holonomic $D$-module for universal deformation of the parameter space (where all the coefficients are deformed from integers). This comes from Gelfand-Kapranov-Zelevinsky theory. Then it is known that for generic polynomials, the $D$-module can be converted to the Gauss-Manin connection. Then our case can be obtained as a restriction of that GM connection to 1d subspace.